# In-memory cache GetOrCreate with MemoryCacheEntryOptions

Tags: caching, asp.net-core

In current implementation `IMemoryCache` interface has the following methods:

```
bool TryGetValue(object key, out object value);
ICacheEntry CreateEntry(object key);
void Remove(object key);
```

We have the possibility to query the cache for an entry in the following way:

```
//first way
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty
(cache.Get<string>("timestamp")))
{
  cache.Set<string>("timestamp", DateTime.Now.ToString());
}

//second way
if (!cache.TryGetValue<string>
("timestamp", out string timestamp))
{
    //
    cache.Set<string>("timestamp", DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

But there is another method that should do what a cache should do (`GetOrCreate`) with a factory parameter:

```
public static TItem GetOrCreate<TItem>(this IMemoryCache cache, object key, Func<ICacheEntry, TItem> factory)
{
   object obj;
   if (!cache.TryGetValue(key, out obj))
   {
     ICacheEntry entry = cache.CreateEntry(key);
     obj = (object) factory(entry);
     entry.SetValue(obj);
     entry.Dispose();
   }
   return (TItem) obj;
}
```

As you can see above, the `Set` method accepts `MemoryCacheEntryOptions` or any `absoluteExpirationRelativeToNow`, `absoluteExpiration`, etc dates (https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/12f998d69703fb0f62b5cb1c123b76d63e0d04f0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs), but `GetOrCreate` method doesn't support that type of 'per-entry-expiration-date' for when we create a new entry.

I'm trying to figure out if i'm missing something or if i should do a PR to add those methods.

Annex:

```
public static ICacheEntry SetValue(this ICacheEntry entry, object value)
{
   entry.Value = value;
   return entry;
 }
```

Opened an issue here: https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/392 in order to get some more feedback.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have understood correctly, but you can set all the 'per-entry-expiration-date' options on the entry you are receiving as the parameter to your factory:

```
string timestamp = cache.GetOrCreate("timestamp", entry =>
{
    entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
});
```

```
string timestamp = cache.GetOrCreate("timestamp", entry =>
{
    entry.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
});
```

All the `MemoryCacheEntryOptions` are available on `ICacheEntry`.

Comment: Hmm...Yea...It looks like all `Set` methods will only set an entry's value + any 'per-entry-expiration-date' that you specify and you have access to those options inside that factory as they are part of `ICacheEntry`. Why didn't i think of that?

Comment: Just want to share my 2 cents: If you copy-paste the first code-block, insert your logic, have an async task in it and thereafter change to `async entry` because your editor starts to complain, don't forget to also change to `_cache.GetOrCreateAsync`, else this expiration won't work! You can still `await` your logic and return a normal object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```cs
_cache.GetOrCreate(
    key,
    entry => {
        entry.SetAbsouluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        return response;
    }
);
```

Also, you can refer to this [page](https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/decorator-pattern-in-asp-net-core)  for a detailed explanation